# X3D-Edit won't install in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to use X3D-Edit in Netbeans as I'm making a java project and need to import .x3d files in, I've been following the steps provided at https://savage.nps.edu/X3D-Edit/

However, when I get to the 'Available Plugins' stage, and check the X3D-Edit plugin to install, a pop up window appears saying that I need to install other plugins in order for it to work and can't see the majority of them in the list. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: What version of Netbeans do you have? Can you post a screenshot of the dialog with the window saying you need other plugins and a screenshot of your Tools->Plugins->Settings page. It worked for me on Netbeans 8.1. It installed ApacheXmlApis, KMLEditor X3D-Edit,and Xj3DWrapper libraries automatically. My guess is you didn't setup the update center correctly.

Comment: I have Netbeans 7.4, so I'm guessing I need the latest updated version? And when it comes to the plugins dialog window, it says:
`The plugin Apache Resolver Library 1.2 is requested in version >= 1.27.1.12 but only 1.25.1.12 was found.
The plugin Xerces Integration is requested in version >= 1.34.1.281 but only 1.32.1.281 was found.
The plugin Auto Update Services is requested in version >= 1.45.3 but only 1.42.2 was found.
The plugin Settings API is requested in version >= 1.44.1 but only 1.42.1 was found.
The plugin File System API is requested in version >= 8.10.1 but only 8.8.1 was found.`